# Exists only to defeat instantiation in singleton

Tags: singleton

In many of the Singleton examples, I have come across constructor having comment as "Exists only to defeat instantiation", can you please give me details and explain more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to create a private constructor when implementing the Singleton pattern so that the default constructor cannot be used to instantiate multiple Singleton objects.

See the example from Wikipedia's [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example) article.

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {   }

    public static synchronized SingletonDemo getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonDemo ();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

By making a private constructor, you insure that the compiler can't make a default constructor with the same signature, which forces any client code to call the `getInstance()` method.

Comment: Hello, can you give singleton classes methods and variables etc and initialize them in another, non-default, constructor? And then have the getInstance() method call that constructor? I was wondering if this is the proper usage of a singleton. Thank you.

Comment: @Ogen Yes, you can do that. You'd just make that constructor private too, and pass arguments to the other getInstance() method.